# Asp.net Webforms Validation - RegularExpressionValidator

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have a webforms form that when I submit, I need to validate.  This is completely new to me but here is what I have.  Right now, when I click to submit, even with blank form, it posts.  I need it to validate first.  I think my issue may be with jquery and PreventDefault().  Also, how do I get this to work with the recaptcha that I've added?  It just bypasses that as well on submit.

Client side code:

```
                <form id="contactForm">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="frmFirstName" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" CssClass="error" ID="FirstNameValid" ControlToValidate="frmFirstName" Text="Please enter your first name"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 pad_lr_8">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="frmLastName" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" CssClass="error" ID="LastNameValid" ControlToValidate="frmLastName" Text="Pleaseenter your last name"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="frmEmail" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" CssClass="error" ID="EmailValid" ControlToValidate="frmEmail" Text="Please enter your email"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row pad_tb_8">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"  Rows="10" CssClass="form-control" ID="frmMessage"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" CssClass="error" ControlToValidate="frmMessage" Text="Please enter your message"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-7" style="padding-right: 8px;">                                
                            <recaptcha:RecaptchaControl ID="recaptcha" runat="server" Theme="white" PublicKey="" PrivateKey=""/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                            <button type="submit" runat="server" OnServerClick="SendEmail" class="btn btn-orange">Send <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 hidden-md hidden-lg">
                            <button type="submit" runat="server" OnServerClick="SendEmail" class="btn btn-orange">Send <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row pad_tb_8">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblResult"></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
     jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
          $("#contactForm").submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to ensures that the user does not skip a form entry field, you have to use ASP.NET VALIDATION SERVER CONTROLS which is RequiredFieldValidator control. Rather than RegularExpressionValidator control, cause the purpose of this control is only to checks that the user’s entry matches a pattern defi ned by a regular expression. This control is good to use to check e-mail addresses and phone numbers based on the given regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the RegularExpression validators (which AFAIK won't fire unless you put something in the field), you need to add RequiredFieldValidators to make sure the user puts something in the field.

Set the `Display="Dynamic"` for both validators.